# Cakephp change pagination syntax

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.6

I'm using pagination in Cakephp 2 and I need to change the syntax of the generated URL. Currently when navigating to the second page with pagination the URL takes on this form:

`www.website.com/?title=house&location=london&page=2`

and I want the pagination to look like this:

`www.website.com/?page=2&title=house&location=london`

I assume I have to edit some Cake library files. I've had a look through PaginatorComponent.php and PaginatorHelper.php but couldn't find the place where the url is generated exactly. Hopefully someone has encountered the need to edit these files before and can help.

Comment: Why? You shouldnt care about the order as it is idempotent and totally irrelevant. I bet there are more important things to solve here.

Comment: Very helpful @mark

Comment: If that was a sarcastic comment then you clearly don't understand how HTTP protocol works. Trying to fix something that can't be fixed properly - and shouldn't be fixed, because there is nothing to fix - sounds like a waste of time to me. This question should be closed IMO.

Comment: @mark Maybe I'm interested in a cosmetic change?